# How to rebuild solc on Mac OSX?

Tags: solidity, installation, mac-osx, solc

I need to rebuild solc on OSX. I followed http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing-solidity.html but old version still in place with solc --version. Is there a process to remove existing solc before building it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We really should put in place something for updating solidity. I assume you mean the one that is compiled from source.

```
cd webthree-umbrella
./webthree-helpers/scripts/ethupdate.sh --no-push --simple-pull --project solidity
./webthree-helpers/scripts/ethbuild.sh --no-git --project solidity --cores 4 -DEVMJIT=0
```

add an --all flag to the build.sh after project if you also want to update Mix and Alethzero. Let me know if you have any more problems on the solidity gitter.